# very basic SQLite table design

Tags: sqlite, relational-database

I don't understand the fundamental set-up of tables in SQLite.

Let's say I have three tables:

```
Studio Table
studioID  studioName
--------  --------
1         Lucasfilm
2         Amblin Entertainment
3         Zoetrope Studios

Movie Table
movieID   movieName        studioID    actorID
--------  --------        --------    --------
1         Star Wars            1          1
2         Indiana Jones        1          1
3         Back to the Future   2          3
4         Apocalypse Now       3          2

Actor Table
actorID  lastName     firstName
-------- --------     --------
1        Ford         Harrison
2        Fishburne    Laurence
3        Lloyd        Christopher
```

This structure doesn't allow for the fact that Harrison Ford and Laurence Fishburne were **both** in *Apocalypse Now*. What would be a conventional way to represent Ford and Fishburne acting in the same movie using similar tables? Sorry for the newbie question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be a conventional way to represent both being in the same movie using similar tables?

There is none.

You need another table: `cast`

```
cast table
---------
movieID
actorID
```

Example data:

```
movieID | actorID
 4      | 1
 4      | 2
```

And maybe there should even be another column in the `cast` table:  `roleName`. The same actor could have multiple roles in one movie.

Answer (score 0):

Studio 1 : N Movies -> One table for Studios, one for movies and add a FK from studio in movies.

Movies N : M Actors -> One table for actors, and another that links Movies and actors.